# Spring gem loads in prodction enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment, spring-gem

When I make `rails console`, it gives me this error

```
WARNING: Spring is running in production. To fix this make sure the spring gem is only present in `development` and `test` groups in your Gemfile and make sure you always use `bundle install --without development test` in production
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.4.3)
```

and here is where I have spring gem in the Gemfile

```
group :development do
 # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
 gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
 gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
 gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5.7

# prepare system
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client

ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV RACK_ENV production

# copy source
WORKDIR /app

COPY src/ /app/

# build
RUN bundle update
RUN bundle install --deployment --without development test
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server",  "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p" ,"3000"]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding `-e production` to rails s command

Comment: Same result....

Comment: By any chance spring is installed locally on your machine, and your Dockerfile is picking it up through COPY src/, or you have a cached version of your image which is not using the --without option? You could try rebuilding your image to check.

From the context you provided it seems that spring should not be installed.

Comment: I will delete the image and see